# PHP: Validate Select box after a radio button is selected

Tags: php, html

I am working on a script where need the customers to select options for clothes

S | L | M | XL | Custom (these are all radio buttons)

If the customer selects custom they would have to fill details using dropdown select menu.

I want the php script to validate the dropdowns only when the custom is selected and if standard sizes are selected then it should not validate dropdowns.

here is the php script

```
function customSizes_validation() { 
    if ( empty( $_REQUEST['standard_size'] ) ) {
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Please Select Size', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        return false;

    }
    return true;
}
```

Html

```
    <div class="sizes">

    <h4>Please Select a Size</h4>
        <input class="checkcase" type="radio" id="xs" name="standard_size" value="xs">
           <label for="xs">XS</label>

        <input class="checkcase" type="radio" id="s" name="standard_size" value="s">
           <label for="s">S</label>

        <input class="checkcase" type="radio" id="m" name="standard_size" value="m">
           <label for="m">M</label>

        <input class="checkcase" type="radio" id="l" name="standard_size" value="l">
           <label for="l">L</label>

        <input class="checkcase" type="radio" id="xl" name="standard_size" value="xl">
           <label for="xl">XL</label>

        <input class="checkcase" type="radio" id="xxl" name="standard_size" value="xxl">
           <label for="xxl">XXL</label>

        <input class="checkcase" type="radio" id="xxxl" name="standard_size" value="xxxl">
           <label for="xxxl">XXXL</label>

        <br><br>

        <input class="checkcase" type="radio" id="custom" name="standard_size" value="custom">
           <label for="custom">Custom</label>
</div>


<div class="clear"></div>


<div class="custom-sizes">
<div class="custom-size-options">

<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-3 selections">
<label>Waist<span class="show_required"> *</span></label>
    <select class="pant_waist validate" name="pant_waist">
        <option value="select">Select</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="26">26</option>

    </select>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3 selections">
    <label>Hip<span class="show_required"> *</span></label>
    <select class="pant_hip validate" name="pant_hip">
        <option value="select">Select</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="31">31</option>
        <option value="32">32</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can check the value of any form inputs and checkboxes using PHP:

```
function customSizes_validation() { 
if ( empty( $_REQUEST['standard_size'] ) ) {
    wc_add_notice( __( 'Please Select Size', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
    return false;

}

if ( $_REQUEST['standard_size'] === 'custom' )
{
   // DO VALIDATION FOR CUSTOM
}

return true;
}
```

Also, don't forget to add `<form>` and `</form>` at beginning and ending of your form, as it seems you omitted those in your sample code, *just sayin'*.

You can also make this check in javascript:

*Though many ways of implementing this exist, this is one way to do it.*

```
var std_size = document.querySelector("[name='standard_size']:checked").value;

if ( std_size === 'custom' )
{
    // DO SOMETHING...
}
```

Comment: Hey @cram2208 thanks fo your response but I was wondering what do I do for validating the custom selection. 1. Do I need to use foreach ? 2. Can I target id instead of the name in php as I have more than one select box. `if ( $_REQUEST['standard_size'] === 'custom' )
{
   // DO VALIDATION FOR CUSTOM
} ` Thanks

Comment: Do you mean: What to do to validate custom fields in case custom checkbox is checked? If that's the case, what do you need to validate exactly? How do you want the date entered to be validated?

Comment: Hey @cram2208 I want to validate the select boxes if custom is selected the select boxes in the code having name pant_waist and pant_hip if they are not selected it shoud give and error only if the custom radio button is selected

Comment: You can then replace the `//DO SOMETHING` part with your select box validation code. The validation code will only work if `standard_size` is *custom*.

Comment: With $_REQUEST[...], you can replace the "..." with any field names included in your form. I.e. standard_size, pant_waist, or pant_hip. In the case of the two lasts, select dropdown menu will always send as a value the selected element in the list, so you can just retrieve the value as you would a normal text input field.

Comment: Got it. Finally got it to work. I was a little confused at first as to how to go about it. Appreciate your help.

Comment: You can then accept my answer if it solves your issue. :-)